# How can i copy values from different workbook based on multiple criterias?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have the Code that copies the values and gives me the values but not the one that i Need. I feel that I am Close but something is missing. The Code copies the whole worksheet of the workbook and i Need the values that meet the criterias.

I have this  main workbook[image: Main Workbook]and i want to take Information from different workbooks which have the same Format, for example this  [image: one] and I want, in the main workbook, to paste the values in some range based on the criterias in the first three columns **("SSL";"Baureihe";"Produktionsjahr")**

this is the Code that i have done till now

```
    Sub Transfer ()
    
    Dim SSl As String
    Dim Baureihe As String
    Dim Produktionsjahr As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim Tfile As Workbook
    Dim shData As Worksheet, shOutput As Worksheet
    Dim rg As Range, ra As Range
    Dim i As Long, row As Long, j As Long
    Set shData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Transponieren")
    
    filename = Application.getOpenFilename("Excel file (*.xlsm),*.xlsm", , "Select File")
    
    If filename = Empty then
     Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set Tfile = Application.Workbooks.Open(filename)
    Set shOutput = Tfile.Worksheets("Transponieren")
    Set rg = shData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set ra = shOutput.range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    
    row = 2
    
    For i = 2 To rg.Rows.Count

            SSL = Sheets("Transponieren").Cells(i, 1).Value
            Baureihe = Sheets("Transponieren").Cells (i , 2).Value
            Produktionsjahr = Sheets("Transponieren") .Cells(i, 3).Value

        For j = 2 To ra.Rows.Count
    
            If ra.Cells(j, 1).Value = SSL And _
            ra.Cells(j, 2).Value = Baureihe And _
            ra.Cells(j, 3).Value = Produktionsjahr Then

   Tfile.Sheets("Transponieren").Range("A" & i & ":E" & i).Copy _ 
  Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Transponieren").Range("K" & j & ":O" & j)

     row = row + 1
     Application.CutCopyMode = False

            End if
        Next j
    Next i
     
    End Sub
```

I am new at vba Excel, i tried various way but i can't seem to see why this Code doesn't copy only the values that i need.  Thanks in Advance

Comment: This line looks odd `Range("A" & i 6 ":E" & i)`

Comment: sorry, it should be Range ```("A" & i & ":E" & i)```.  i will edit it now

Comment: `Destionation` should that be destination?

Comment: Yeah, it copies the _values_ from the file that i select and then paste in the specific range. But the range could Change.

Comment: Does that explain the misspelling of destination?

Comment: No , not really. I mean the ```Destination``` is fine just i think the copy part doesnt work properly. It doesnt give me any **error* tho. it gives me values but wrong ones.

Comment: I think you have a parameter name spelled incorrectly `range("a1").Copy destionation=range("b1")` gives `copy method failed error`.  Are you getting an error

Comment: No i dont have any error , just it wont give me the values from the selected file correctly.

Comment: Try pasting the working code instead of re-writing it

Comment: `Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.xlsm),*.xlsm", , "Select File")` word files doesn't come as xlsm, "Wroksheet" is not a thing, `arr` isn't defined, "file Name" shouldn't be separated

Comment: Sorry but i dont know how to do that. Should i start doing some other apporach or what do you mean by pasting ?

Comment: ```Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.xlsm", , "Select File")``` is changed to **.xlsx** , and ``arr`` is removed.

Comment: What AsUsual means is copy your code from the VB editor and paste it here. As it stands with the typos your code cannot even possibly run.

Comment: I tried but i cannot do that, i am also new on Stackoverflow. Sorry

Comment: Why not? Select your code in Excel, copy it, edit your question, delete your existing code, paste the new code in and add the code tags.

Comment: It doesnt allow me to do that. Maybe because i am new at Stackoverflow and cant just copy and paste codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Code that helped me finish my taks. Just if someone needed.

```
Option Explicit

Sub transfer()
 Dim fileName As Variant, a() As Variant, b() As Variant, c As Variant, i As Long, j As Long
 Dim sh1 As Worksheet, wb2 As Workbook, sh2 As Worksheet
 '
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Set sh1 = Sheets("Transponieren")

 fileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel file (*.xlsx),*.xlsx", , "Select File")
 If fileName = False Then Exit Sub
 Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Open(fileName)
 Set sh2 = wb2.Sheets("Transponieren")
 `
 a = sh1.Range("A2:C" & sh1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row)
 b = sh2.Range("A2:E" & sh2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row)
 ReDim c(1 To UBound(a), 1 To 5)
 For i = 1 To UBound(a)
   For j = 1 To UBound(b)
     If a(i, 1) = b(j, 1) And a(i, 2) = b(j, 2) And a(i, 3) = b(j, 3) Then
       c(i, 1) = b(j, 1)
       c(i, 2) = b(j, 2)
       c(i, 3) = b(j, 3)
       c(i, 4) = b(j, 4)
       c(i, 5) = b(j, 5)
       Exit For
     End If
   Next
 Next
 wb2.Close False
 sh1.Range("K2").Resize(UBound(a), 5).Value = c
End Sub
```